# View saved in one database but gathering data from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a view for a query I do manually every day. I am trying to save the view in database 1 while my data is in database 2. I tried a script like

```
USE Database1
go

Create view dbo.w_tab1 as

USE Database2
go

Select........
```

But I get an error. How do I do this

Comment: Don't just tell us that *I get an error* - we can't read your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **TELL US** what that error is, exactly and precisely!

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, but I will remember it. But I got the answere. Thx for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a qualified object name:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.w_tab1 AS SELECT ... FROM database2.dbo.table;
```